# JUnit testing simple GUI

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have built a simple GUI for log-in page for the class. However, JUnit really trips me on that. From my understanding, I can't test buttons and such, only functions attached to them. I do have a hardcoded password and user name- it's ok per requirement.

In my case, I have to have 4 tests. I want to test if users log in successfully, unsuccessfully, if the clear button works and if a log file is being created.

PLease suggest what could I do. They way I have done it doesnt work :)
My 1 test case

```
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.passwordText.setText("John");
        gui.userText.setText("123123");
        gui.loginButton.doClick();
        
//      success.getText()
                
        assertEquals("Welcome to junit.","Welcome to junit.");


    }
```

```
public static void logInSucccess(String username, Boolean isLoginSuccess) {

        try {
            String path = "Log.txt";
            File f = new File(path);
            if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            String log;
            if (isLoginSuccess) {
                log = "\n" + getTimeStamp() + " User - " + username + "-" + "login successful.";
            } else {
                log = "\n" + getTimeStamp() + " User - " + username + "-" + "login not successful.";
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));
            writer.write(log);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {

            userText.setText("");
            passwordText.setText("");

        }
        if (e.getSource() == loginButton) {
            String user = userText.getText();
            String password = passwordText.getText();
            Boolean isLoginSuccess;

            if (user.equals("John") && password.equals("123123")) {
                failure.setText("");
                success.setText("Log in successful");
                isLoginSuccess = true;
            }

            else {
                failure.setText("Incorect, try again");
                isLoginSuccess = false;

            }
            logInSucccess(user, isLoginSuccess);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to have tests that actually interact with the UI as a "user" would (a "click robot" if you so will)? If so: that is a separate kind of test: an UI test.

Comment: Just JUnit will do. some basic stuff, just consused and after reading Stack didn't really clarify

Answer (score 2):

You could try to build unit tests that take advantage of the [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html). However [Marathon](https://marathontesting.com/blog-posts/unit-testing-swing-apps/) has taken a different approach to tackle the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Unfortunately in my case is a stand-alone GUI app and I can't really use Web-related testing tools :(

Comment: @SergeyV. Marathon/JavaDriver *is* for Swing apps, not web apps. Ditto `java.awt.Robot`.

Comment: I'm sorry you mention a standalone GUI app in Java and I am assuming Java Swing. So what does GUI mean in your case?